# How to find path from where current process/executable is running?

Tags: unix, path

I am running some executables while connected to a local unix server box.

Say, I'm trying to run an executable 'abc'. Now the server might have provided an alias for 'abc'.. How do I get to know of this path? As in, if I invoke 'abc', it might actually run it from, say, /opt/corp/xyz/abc .. How do I get to know from what path I'm invoking the executable?

By the way I'm running on HP-UX :D

Answer (score 10):

"`which abc`" to show which `abc` you would be calling

or "`alias`" to list aliases

perhaps "echo $0" from inside a script, or retrieving argv[0] some other way.

Answer (score 4):

If you are running using the PATH environment variable, you could try:

```
$ which abc
```

or

```
$ whereis abc
```

If there is a symbolic link for the command and you want to know the *"real"* target, you can use something like:

```
$ readlink /opt/corp/xyz/abc
```

I do not have access to an HPUX system in front of me right now, but this should work:

```
$ ls -l /opt/local/bin/wish
lrwxr-xr-x  1 root  admin  22 Feb  3 21:56 /opt/local/bin/wish@ -> /opt/local/bin/wish8.5
$ readlink /opt/local/bin/wish
/opt/local/bin/wish8.5
```

If the command is based on an alias, the following will reveal the alias definition.

```
$ alias abc
```

depending on how your system is configured, the above commands should provide answers to multiple variations of your question.

in Perl:

```
$running_script = $0;
```

from Python, see SO [How to get filename of the __main__ module in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/606561/how-to-get-filename-of-the-main-module-in-python)

Answer (score 3):

Does HP-UX have the "which" command?  Run:

```
which abc
```

If you have it, the `which` command will tell you which abc program will run from your `$PATH`.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks all!
'which' was the commmand I was after! I'm facepalming myself now as I had already known the command (in Ubuntu)..
And it does work like a charm in HP-UX!

EDIT : 'whereis' suggested by popcnt is even more appropriate!
Thanx a lot man!

Comment: if you like mine, go ahead and +1 it, and if satisfactory, you could mark it as the answer to your question. That is typically what you'll see here on SO, instead of an "answer" from the original poster.

Answer (score 1):

From a command line terminal:

$ which abc

/opt/corp/xyz/abc

Answer (score 1):

The correct way to get the path of a script on Unix is:

```
dir=$(cd $(dirname "$0"); pwd)
```

Background: $0 is the filename+path of the script relative to the current directory. It can be absolute (`/...`) or relative (`../`, `dir/...`). So the `$(dirname "$0")` returns the path (without the filename). Mind the quotes; "$0" can contain spaces and other weird stuff.

We then `cd` into that directory and `pwd` will return the absolute path where we end up.

Works for `ksh` and `bash`.

In a C program, you should check `argv[0]`. I'm not sure whether the shell will put the complete path in there. If you have trouble, I suggest to wrap your executable in a small script which prepares the environment and then invoke your executable with:

```
exec "$dir/"exe "$@"
```