# Trouble running a compiled app which includes singleton

Tags: python, singleton, pyqt, pyqt4, py2exe

I'm having trouble running a compiled app which includes singleton, the .pyw compilation proccess goes just fine, but when I attempt to run the resulting .exe, it writes an error log with the message shown below:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.pyw", line 16, in <module>
  File "tendo\singleton.pyc", line 20, in __init__
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute '__file__'
```

this is how I'm calling singleton:

```
from tendo import singleton
me = singleton.SingleInstance()
```

Comment: Please put your code too in order to be more specific

Comment: How are you "compiling" this app? `py2exe`? Something else? Does it work before being packed into an `.exe` file?

Comment: @Senderle: I'm using py2exe to make the windows executable;

Comment: @GodMan: The code is too long, and anyway, if I don't include tendo, I can make use of the app. but the use of singleton is a requirement, since I can't allow more than 1 instance of the application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [tendo](https://github.com/ssbarnea/tendo/)'s singleton module [makes use](https://github.com/ssbarnea/tendo/blob/master/tendo/singleton.py#L20) of `sys.modules['__main__'].__file__` to find the main directory. In py2exe it doesn't exist, that's why you get this error.

You can fix it with [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/608036/11343). In tendo/singleton.py, line 20 you have:

```
self.lockfile = os.path.normpath(tempfile.gettempdir() + '/' +
  os.path.splitext(os.path.abspath(sys.modules['__main__'].__file__))[0] \
  .replace("/","-").replace(":","").replace("\\","-") + '-%s' % flavor_id +'.lock')
```

Replace with something like this:

```
path_to_script = get_main_dir()  #see linkd answer
self.lockfile = os.path.normpath(tempfile.gettempdir() + '/' +  path_to_script
  .replace("/","-").replace(":","").replace("\\","-") + '-%s' % flavor_id +'.lock')
```

Report this as an issue to the author, and/or make a pull request with the fix.