# Proper way of getting path of main script from library in Python

Tags: python, path, relative-path, inspect

I'm writing a Python library which which you can load an object from a file and do something with it. For convenience, I'd like to make it so that people can provide three kinds of paths:

1. A path starting with a "/", which will be interpreted as an absolute path
2. A path starting with a "~/", which will be interpreted as relative to the user's home directory (for which I plan to use `os.path.expanduser`)
3. A path starting with neither, which would be interpreted as relative to the directory of the top-level script that is importing my library.

My question is: what is the best way of approaching the third case? The two ways I have come across on Stack Overflow are both kind of klugey:

1)

```
import __main__
if hasattr(__main__, "__file__"):
    script_dir = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__main__.__file__))
```

2. 

```
import inspect
frame_info = inspect.stack()[-1]
mod = inspect.getmodule(frame_info[0])
script_dir = os.path.dirname(mod.__file__)
```

Obviously both of these will fail in the case that we're running from an interactive terminal or something, and in that case I would want to fall back to just treating it as an absolute path.

Anyway, I get the sense that using inspect like this in a library is frowned upon, but the other way seems klugey as well. Is there a better way to do this that I'm unaware of?

Comment: You haven't mentioned the `working directory`, are you aware of that? An unprefixed path is common practice to be relative to the current working directory. You should also take a look at the built-in `pathlib` package before you create your package

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get filename of the \_\_main\_\_ module in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/606561/how-to-get-filename-of-the-main-module-in-python)

Comment: Sounds like there isn't actually a problem with the first approach other than you finding it "klugey", is there?

Comment: @mkrieger1 I guess the klugeyness was a tip off that I was doing something a bit funny, since it's something for which I would expect a simple answer. In this case, I was looking for `getcdw`, even though it's slightly different.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the built-in package `pathlib`'s `getcwd` method. It defaults to the root folder of the top package.

*Will not work if you change the working directory. Although, an unprefixed path is common practice to be relative to the working directory.*

```py
import pathlib
print(pathlib.Path.cwd())

>>> A:\Programming\Python\generalfile
```

Comment: Thank you for this -- I believe the `working directory` is exactly what I was looking for. Of course, if you run a script from a different directory, then that is different from the directory of the script, but I think in that case maybe you still want the working directory, if that's the convention for unprefixed paths.

Quick question: is there a difference between pathlib.Path.cwd() and os.getcwd()? Why use one over the other?

Comment: [`pathlib` actually uses `os.getcwd()`.](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/9568622c9983b682b2a2a7bacfd3c341028ea099/Lib/pathlib.py#L1125) I prefer using **pathlib** as having that extra layer of a built-in package designed specifically for filesystem paths seems more stable to me